# When running the 'hello world' test container for new installation of Docker, i get an OCI runtime error

Tags: docker, centos

I've installed Docker on Centos 7 using the yum process. Below is the output for `systemctl status docker.service -l`:

```
       ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-01-02 14:11:09 GMT; 1h 15min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 136537 (dockerd)
   Memory: 71.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─136537 /usr/bin/dockerd
           └─136556 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml

Jan 02 15:00:33 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:00:33.157175048Z" level=error msg="c60a6261b7381f5739fa11e6df8b4219d8db94e766c6e4c8c4c2d45a44ee03a5 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Jan 02 15:00:33 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:00:33.157230927Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.35/containers/c60a6261b7381f5739fa11e6df8b4219d8db94e766c6e4c8c4c2d45a44ee03a5/start returned error: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c60a6261b7381f5739fa11e6df8b4219d8db94e766c6e4c8c4c2d45a44ee03a5/log.json: no such file or directory): docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: unknown"
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44.837926048Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/containers/create type="*events.ContainerCreate"
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f/shim.sock" debug=false module="containerd/tasks" pid=145298
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f module="containerd/tasks"
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44.899560066Z" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44.899585062Z" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Jan 02 15:09:44 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:44.921068216Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/containers/delete type="*events.ContainerDelete"
Jan 02 15:09:45 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:45.309201262Z" level=error msg="3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Jan 02 15:09:45 colossus dockerd[136537]: time="2018-01-02T15:09:45.309254679Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.35/containers/3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f/start returned error: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f/log.json: no such file or directory): docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: unknown"
```

The error i get (sudo docker run hello-world) is:

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/3e04ce212f3603d2b93339494d74e305ea6a2e8d08a3ba9c30a0c741c9232b1f/log.json: no such file or directory): docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: unknown.
    ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

docker --version

```
 Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

and here is the docker info

```
Containers: 27
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 27
Images: 47
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-135160107-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 14.4GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 25.82GB
 Metadata Space Used: 12.6MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.135GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: N/A (expected: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f)
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 88
Total Memory: 125.6GiB
Name: colossus
ID: HV7I:KP2J:N6SQ:SAEP:MWSO:O5T3:Y2PE:L6TL:2D6L:IHVD:SQ3E:TM5P
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: `docker version` and `docker info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have an old package installed that is breaking runc. Make sure to upgrade your operating system to the current release (for CentOS, this is 1708, or the RHEL equivalent of 7.4). Others have [reported similar issues](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35906) related to packages being out of date.

Answer (score 1):

I had 2 systems with identical CentOS 7.2 versions and kernel.  Had this problem with one but not the other.   Comparing package versions showed a difference in the version of containerd.io -- I downgraded that on the non-working version and it worked:

```
$ sudo yum downgrade containerd.io-1.2.0-3.el7
Removed:
 containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.4-3.1.el7

Installed:
  containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.0-3.el7
```